# graphics magick get info from "-format"

Tags: graphicsmagick

http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-format

"When used with the identify utility, or the convert utility with output written to the 'info:-' file specification, use this option to print information about the image in a format of your choosing. You can include the image filename, type, width, height, Exif data, or other image attributes by embedding special format characters:"

How to get the "format" data ?

I have

```
gm  convert  -resize '250x50>^'  "g.jpg" -gravity Center -extent '250x50>' -format '%w %h'  g2.jpg
```

But nothing is printed or output.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is a bit obtuse... you need to add the `info:`` file:

```
gm convert image.png -resize 100x100 -format '%w %h' info:-
100 33
```